# How to navigate to other php pages using drop down list?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to navigate to different web pages using a drop down list and submit. I have three forms:

- main.php
- two.php
- three.php

In my main.php page I have a drop down list consisting of only two options 'second' and 'third'. How can I use these two options to navigate to other php pages? For example, if I selected the option 'two' and click submit, the page should then take me to the second.php page. And if I select option 'three', I will be taken to the third.php page.

Also, once I am directed to one of the php pages, how can I then be able to go back to the 'main.php' page if I decide to go to the other php page instead? (I thought perhaps the use of a back button).

Below is part of my 'main.php' page:

```
<label>Select the page you wish to go:</label></td>
    <select name="pages"/>
        <option value="two.php">Second</option>
        <option value="three.php">Third</option>
    </select></td>
```

Comment: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/navmenu.html

Comment: Try this - `<select name="pages" onChange="document.location.href = this.value">`

Answer (score 3):

On `<select></select>` value change :

***HTML :***

```
<select name="pages" onChange="my_function(this)">
```

***JavaScript :***

```
function my_function(element){
     document.location.href = element.value
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8zZ8/2/)

On `<button></button>` click :

***HTML :***

```
<button onClick="my_function()"></button>
```

***JavaScript :***

```
function my_function(){
     document.location.href = document.querySelector('select[name="pages"]').value
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8zZ8/1/)

Comment: this is great and it works but how can I change it so that I press a button like submit for it to change pages?

Comment: @sass : Updated with examples.

Comment: I honestly want to say that it is up and running but the updated html and javascript doesn't seem to be working. Maybe this is one of my errors, so I'll probably go over it again, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @sass : `querySelector()` selects the first `select` with the `name="page"`.So maybe there are other elements with this type and attribute value,so you better use `id` selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple things. If you dont wan't to rely on javascript, make the form submit to a file like `router.php`.

inside `router.php` put:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['pages']) {
        header('Location: ' . $_POST['pages']);
    }
```

Which will effectively forward the request to the page you submitted in the select.

You also have to change your html a bit:

```
<label>Select the page you wish to go:</label></td>
<form method="post" action="router.php">
   <select name="pages"/>
      <option value="two.php">Second</option>
      <option value="three.php">Third</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="go there" />
</form>
```

If you are fine with javascript go with *@notulysses*'s answer, its way easier and quicker.
Using `POST` values directly in a header method is kinda nasty imo.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery solution

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <form id="frm"  method="post" action="" >
  <label>Select the page you wish to go:</label>
    <select name="pages"/>
       <option value="two.php">Second</option>
       <option value="three.php">Third</option>
   </select>
  <input type="submit" name="sub"  value="Finish" />
 </form>
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
      $('#frm').on('submit',function () {
          var nextPage= $('select option:selected').val();  
          $(this).attr('action',nextPage);
          return true;
      });
```

Happy Coding :)